# Microsoft public repository rpm downloads failed with gpgcheck enabled with reposync

Tags: linux, gpg, signature

I’m facing an issue to download the patches (rpm) from Microsoft public repository site with gpgcheck=1.

Repository site: [https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/](https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/%E2%80%82) 
To download all rpm I have followed the steps to import repository into my server and added same configuration in yum repo.s d directory.

```
[packages-microsoft-com-prod]
name=packages-microsoft-com-prod
baseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

On this path there are 2 keys "packages.microsoft.com/keys" in .asc format.

Using

```
reposync -g -p //appl/data/Patch/test/test_microsoft --download-metadata --repoid=packages-microsoft-com-prod
```

trying to downloads all rpm,
but I find there some rpm which are continuously failing because of missing key.

```
blobfuse-1.0.1-RC-preview-rhel74.rpm due to failed signature check.
testrpm-1.0.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check.
hellomicrosoft-1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check.
libmsquic-2.0.2-1.x86_64.rpm, due to missing GPG key.
microsoft-r-client-mlm-3.5.2.rpm due to failed signature check.
microsoft-r-client-packages-3.5.2.rpm due to failed signature check.
mssql-cli-0.11.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check.
mssql-cli-0.12.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check.
mssql-cli-0.13.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check.
powershell-preview-7.1.0_preview.4-1.rhel.7.x86_64.rpm due to failed signature check
```

The following commands show that there are few rpm with KEY but no signature:

```
# rpm -K blobfuse-1.0.1-RC-preview-rhel74.rpm
blobfuse-1.0.1-RC-preview-rhel74.rpm: sha1 md5 OK
# rpm -K mssql-cli-0.11.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
mssql-cli-0.11.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: sha1 md5 OK
```

<sup>[Manually transcribed from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuZNl.png)].</sup>

Looking for the way to resolve this.

Comment: Where are you following the steps from?

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt: (1) [Please don’t post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216)  (2) When you see a blob of text that doesn’t look like English, check to see whether it’s a code block (including excerpts from files or tty sessions) and format it appropriately.  Likewise, filenames and individual commands should also be formatted as code.  ... (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) ... (3) When you’re editing a post, look out for spelling errors (and errors in grammar, punctuation, capitalization, etc.) and fix them too (if you’re reasonably sure that you know the rules of English well enough to do so correctly).  (4) Stack Exchange frowns on things like ‘‘thanks in advance’’ in questions.  When you see something like that *in a question you’re editing anyway,* take it out.